# How to create a second header for woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to create a second header. One to implement in all pages of Woocommerce. The other one on the other pages of Wordpress. How can I write the code?

get_header('shop'); get_header('shop2');

Answer (score 1):

There are few steps to do that:
 - Duplicate your header.php file and name it header-{smth}.php. Replace {smth} with word that you want. For example: header-shop2.php
 - Now you can call get_header('shop2')

Reference: 
https://www.webascender.com/blog/create-multiple-headers-footers-wordpress/